# How does one say lowlands in contemporary Latin?

Tags: contemporary-latin, new-latin, modern-life

How would one write the expression "lowlands" in contemporary Latin? Would it be like in Spanish, *terra bassa*, or would it be something like *terra subiecta* or even *terra infera*?

I would prefer an answer with a source, if possible, but if you do not have one, an educated guess is more than welcome. I personally find *terra infera* reminds me too much of the netherworld or something of the sort, but I am not sure of the value of the other options.

Comment: I don't know how well they researched it, but the game developers of Imperator Rome used "infera" for some province names.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a source other than Lewis & Short, but possibly the classical *convallis* or *vallis* could be put to use.

Comment: It seems good, but couldn't that be confused with a valley? Maybe something like _Terrae Vallium_? I also just found this link: 

https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_baixa

It is a play called "lowlands" and the wiki author translates lowlands as _terra demissa_.

Comment: Yes it can be confused with valley, but very few languages have as many words as English, and their words cover more ground (pun intended)

Comment: True, and in most cases I would agree with you.After all, context matters, so there are many words that mean one thing and can mean another in a different context.My main problem though is the differentiation of the two meanings, because they are essentially very different things.In the case of lowlands, we are talking about lands that are closer to the sea in height.Like when we speak of the Netherlands.But when we talk about a valley we are talking about a land that is between mountains or hills.I would hesitate in using a word for valley because of such dissimilarities.Does that make sense?

Comment: Just to add to what I said, because of the character count constraints: They have very different meaning, but are employed in the same _context_ (geography).